# @Value("${welcome}) in springboot is throwing illegal argument exception and could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

```
@RestController
Class MyController{

@Value("${welcome}")
private String welcome;

@RequestMapping("/greet")
public String greetHim(){
  return welcome;
}

}
application.properties:
welcome=welcomeEla
```

The above code is throwing illegal argument exception and saying could not resolve placeholder 'welcome' in value "${welcome}"

If I give a **space between '$' and '{'** it is not throwing any exception but it is **fetching null** value.

Also I tried with environment variable as autowired with @PropertySource("application.properties") over the Class it was also fetching null value (env.getProperty("welcome"))

Can anybody help me in this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where have you placed your application.properties? Is it loaded when the app is started?

Comment: If you're splitting the `${`, you shouldn't be getting `null`. You should literally get the `String` value that you specified, ie. `"$ {welcome}"`, because there's no longer a placeholder there to resolve. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: application.properties file was created automatically and placed under resources folder.
Sry When i was trying with Autowired Environment variable, ithe output was null.
Trying with @Value("$ {welcome}") outputs "$ {welcome}" itself
Reproducable example:
```@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Value("$ {welcome}")
    private String welcome;

    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    public String greetHim() {
        System.out.println("Welcome : " + welcome);
        return welcome;
    }
}
Output:
$ {welcome}```

Comment: We need the [mcve] for your entire use case. How you setup your application, how it's configured and run. Provide the full stack trace as well.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly ,

```
ApplicationContextProvider appContext = new ApplicationContextProvider();
Environment env = appContext.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
// env.getProperty() works!!!
String temp = env.getProperty("welcome");
System.out.println(temp) ;
```

you run this code. And make sure it works. Do you try @Value("${welcome.toString()}") if it works

Comment: I tried your code. But still it is giving output as null. Following is the code i tried.
```@RestController
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider;

    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    public String greetHim() {
        Environment env = applicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        String temp = env.getProperty("welcome");
        System.out.println(temp) ;
        return  temp;
    }
}```

Comment: The below is the ApplicationContextProvider.
```@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}```

Comment: Do you try ```@Value("${welcome.toString()}")``` if it works
it is throwing ```illegal argument exception and could not resolve place holder````.
if i give space between '$ and '{' it is giving output as ```$ {welcome.toString()}```